# Can $p$-Sylows be Cyclic?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory

This is from Dummut and Foote *Abstract Algebra*, 4.5.45.

> Find the generators for a Sylow $p$-group of $S_{2p}$, where $p$ is an odd prime. Show that this is abelian of order $p^2$.

I   have shown that the order of the $p$-Sylow is $p^2$. ALso, I have proved that if $H$ is a $p$-Sylow, since $Z(H)$ is non-tirival and then $H / Z(H)$ is cyclic, and it follows that $H$ is abelian.

Now, I know my two options for the group of order $p^2$ that $H$ is isomorphic to are $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ and  $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ x  $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$. In both cases I can find generators.

**My Questions:**

A solution I found online ignored the possibiliy that $H$ is isomorphic to  $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$. Is that not a possibility?

Why do they specify $p$ is an odd prime? is $p=2$ a different case?

Comment: Note that the order of a 2-Sylow of $S_{2(2)}$ is $2^3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group $S_{2(2)} = S_4$ has elements of order $4$. But the group $S_{2p}$ with $p$ an odd prime does not. You would need the decomposition of the element into disjoint cycles to involve cycles of lengths $1$, $p$, and $p^2$, with at least one cycle of length $p^2$, and that is impossible if you are in $S_{2p}$ with $p$ odd.

In general, yes, Sylow subgroups can be cyclic. But your group here does not have elements of order $p^2$, so that possibility is excluded a priori.

Comment: So, this is because all cycles in $S_{2p}$ permute up to $2p$ elements, and so there is no cycle that can permute $p^2$ elements if $p^2 > 2p$, correct?

Comment: @Jess: Yes, no cycle in $S_n$ can involve more than $n$ elements, after all.